# Winning percentage (white win/draw/black win) in chess960/9LX in 2021?

Tags: chess-variants, draw, database, statistics, chess960

> How does the winning percentage (white win/draw/black win) in chess 960 (Fischer random) compare to that of regular chess?

The above was asked here: [Winning percentage in chess 960](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/16344/winning-percentage-in-chess-960). I would like to re-ask this question with the ff changes:

1. but now in 2021 (the previous question was in 2017. in the past 4 years, there has been a fide world fischer random championship. there's also [this](https://www.uschesschamps.com/2020-champions-showdown-chess-9lx/overview).)
2. perhaps 1 answer for computers (no need to answer again for computers, if it's about the same as the answer before, I guess) and 1 for humans (the previous question had a computer only answer and so far no human answers)? Or maybe just 1 for humans if this question is otherwise too broad
3. I don't care about sample size. (the answer in previous question didn't answer about humans because of low sample size. even if the sample size is low, I don't mind)

---

follow-up question to brian towers' answer in case it gets deleted (I notice that on this stackexchange site, follow up questions or reasons for downvoting can be removed without warning or explanation!):

> what about the equivalent standard chess percentages please? i figure so we can at least have an understanding of 'not many' just like in the other post. i don't think it has to be dug up from chess-results similarly. i'm expecting there are some kind of statistics already done for this. but anyway i'll award the bounty for now

Comment: The paper on AlphaZero was published at the end of 2017, so I wonder what insights the world of machine learning engines can offer. It looks like the tournament cited in answers to the 2017 question are mostly conventional (e.g. Stockfish).

Comment: @bcdan I got a 2022 update but for classical. [Winning percentage (white win/draw/black win) in classical chess960 as of, say, 2022?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41588/)

Answer (score 2):

Searching on c[hess-results](http://chess-results.com/TurnierSuche.aspx?lan=1) for "960" tournaments played in 2021 gives the following:

[68th PCA Chess 960 Tournament 24th Jan 2021](http://chess-results.com/tnr547234.aspx?lan=1&art=2&rd=5&turdet=YES) W23 D0 B21
[Первенство Владимирской области по шахматам-960](http://chess-results.com/tnr550813.aspx?lan=1&turdet=NO) (rapid) W25 D3 B25
[Турнир по шахматам 960, посвящённый 78-летию со дня рождения 11-го чемпиона мира по шахматам Роберта Фишера](http://chess-results.com/tnr552026.aspx?lan=1) (rapid) W20 D7 B22
[Відкрита Першість СК Нафтохімік- Шахи 960(шахи Фішера) м.Кременчук 27.03.2021р](http://chess-results.com/tnr554661.aspx?lan=1&turdet=YES) (blitz) W35 D5 B23
[8° Choriblitz Atawallpa Chess 960](http://chess-results.com/tnr558603.aspx?lan=1&flag=30&turdet=YES) (blitz) W15 D4 B11
[TORNEO ABIERTO "FISCHER 960" JAQUE PERPETUO AJEDREZ](http://chess-results.com/tnr559634.aspx?lan=1&turdet=YES) (blitz) W4 D0 B2
[ACCENTUS Chess960 Biel International Chess Festival 2021](http://chess-results.com/tnr569012.aspx?lan=1&art=0&turdet=YES) (rapid) W12 D6 B10
[Majstrovstvá v sachu 960 (Fischerov sach) - 4.8.2021; 18:30](http://chess-results.com/tnr570310.aspx?lan=1&turdet=YES) (blitz) W23 D1 B18
[Петергофское лето - 2021. Шахматы Фишера (шахматы 960)](http://chess-results.com/tnr572802.aspx?lan=1&turdet=YES) (rapid) W12 D0 B13
[Torneo Blitz "Camino a la Maestría" Chess 960](http://chess-results.com/tnr576296.aspx?lan=1&turdet=YES) (rapid) W4 D3 B8
[Chess 960 šachmatų turnyras, skirtas UAB „Art Glacio" taurei laimėti](http://chess-results.com/tnr574402.aspx?lan=1&turdet=YES) (rapid) W18 D1 B6

Totals = W191 D30 B158
Percentages = W=50.4% D=7.9% B=41.7%
Note that these are all rapid or blitz, hence not many draws.

Comment: thanks. but what about the equivalent standard chess percentages please? i figure so we can at least have an understanding of 'not many' just like in the other post. i don't think it has to be dug up from chess-results similarly. i'm expecting there are some kind of statistics already done for this. but anyway i'll award the bounty for now